# Kubuntu 19.10 Doesn't Suspend Properly Using Home Folder Encryption?

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, encryption, power-management, 19.10

I have a nearly fresh install of Kubuntu 19.10 and encrypted my home folder using `ecryptfs-migrate-home` using the [typical method](https://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/).

This had led to an issue where, when I suspend my computer by closing the laptop lid, the computer suspends initially, then wakes back up at the log in screen and won't suspend without me hitting sleep in the log in screen.

[image: Power Settings]

What should I do to resolve this issue? I would usually use `ubuntu-bug` but I don't know what package to file a bug against.

**EDIT 0:** The swapfile doesn't exist (I think) because I'm using BTRFS as a filesystem. This is the swapfile entry in fstab:

```
#/swapfile             none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: I'm using BTRFS which doesn't use the swapfile. It is commented out in fstab.

Comment: Have added a bounty from my points bank to draw attention to it, over my head.

Comment: @K7AAY Wow! Thank you so much! That was unexpected.

Comment: More reliable would be the output of `cat /proc/swaps`. Is a [instantaneous wakeups from suspend](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Instantaneous_wakeups_from_suspend)? Did you check `journalctl -x -p warning`? Tried using just `systemd suspend`?

Comment: @PabloBianchi I'm running BTRFS, which doesn't use a swap file, the output of the `cat` command is this: `Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority` with no elements in the table.

Comment: Sarah, you can add to the bounty yourself to draw more attention.

Comment: @K7AAY Are you sure? The typical bounty button isn't at the bottom of the screen and a quick research hasn't been helpful with regards to adding to already exiting bounties. Also, I none of the links in the bounty box itself allow me to add to the bounty.

Comment: My bounty times out in 20 hrs from now; then, you can add more if no one answers.

Comment: @K7AAY I explored more than I would like and asked on more forums than I care to admit, however after a week I just gave up and installed manjaro and opted for the full disk encryption. I haven't had any issues since :) Thanks for the valiant effort!